# How to send message to perticular client in Asp.net (c#) using WebSockets

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket

I am using Microsoft.WebSockets and facing problems in sending messages to perticular client. Currently I have usied WebSocketCollection object and added every new client on it. It allows to broadcast messages to all client. But I want to send message to specific single one i.e. Signalr provides to send messages from server to specific client i.e.

```
Hub.Clients.Client(connectionId).yourClientSideMethod()
```

I want to achieve the same using Microsoft.WebSockets. I have searched alot about it on internet but couldn't be able to find any solution. Please help me in it.

My code is as follows:

```
class ChatWebSocketHandler : WebSocketHandler
{
    private static WebSocketCollection _chatClients = new WebSocketCollection();
    private string _username;

    public ChatWebSocketHandler(string username)
    {
        _username = username;
    }

    public override void OnOpen()
    {
        _chatClients.Add(this);
    }

    public override void OnMessage(string message)
    {
 //for broadcasting messages to all clients
        //_chatClients.Broadcast(this._username + " : " + message);

 //for sending message to individual client i want something like
 _chatClients.Single(x=>x._username.Equals("name")).Send(message);
    }

    public override void OnClose()
    {
        // Free resources, close connections, etc.
        base.OnClose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
clients.SingleOrDefault(r => ((SocketHandler)r).userName == "udara").Send("Hello udara");
```

Comment: Could you explain your solution?)

Comment: You can store connectin id in the database and you can get specific user id from database. After you can send message to selected user.

Comment: @UdaraKasun this works fine but when the user opens the same page in different tab, this line throws exception. Can we have a workaround here?

Comment: Try to generate client id using GUID, and assign them to the client id when new client is connecting